# multiple elements with ng-if and always only 1 of them is shown, can they share the same id?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angular-ng-if

As in title. I want to have 2 elements with ng-if and the same id, only 1 of them is shown at the same time. I am wondering if they can have the same id, since ng-if will remove 1 of the elements, so there will be only 1 element with that id.

I mean not only if it can be done, but also if it's a good way of doing things.

Here is the code sample of what I have in mind (it's been simplified):

```
<span id="elementType" ng-if="vm.type === 1">type1</span>
<span id="elementType" ng-if="vm.type === 2">type2</span>
```

Let's say that vm.type can only have values of 1 and 2.

Edit: Using a class instead of id is not possible for me. I am just wondering if I can use a single id for every element, or do all of them need to have separate id.

Edit2: I cannot use a class and need ids because I make these changes for tests, which rely on testing by ids. I cannot change that, so **using class is not an option** for me and is not an answer to my question at all.

Edit3:  I am also absolutely sure that **there will always be only one of the elements** with ng-if displayed. I only need it for displaying element type, and there will always be exactly one type. If by any chance, the requirements change, it would already require massive changes, compared to which, changing things like displaying of the element type is not a problem at all.

Comment: what do you need an ID for? CSS? Why not use a class then?

Comment: element IDs should be unique across the entire document, and that's required by HTML spec, it's not an angular thing

Comment: yes i see no problem in your code, since one element will be available in DOM at a time.

Comment: @edo.n Precisely. OP's question is about "Will the ID be unique, since Angular will not generate the other elements with the same ID?"

Comment: Sure, but what if he returns to the same code after two months and forget that only ONE of those elements must be shown at a time. I suggest that he guards against that possibility early on. Your idea for using a class is much more robust.

Comment: Unfortunately doing it by class is not possible for me. There must be ids and  im just wondering if I can do it with 1 id or I would be forced to give every element a different id.

Comment: `There must be ids` doesn't answer my question : _why_ MUST there be IDs? I see no valid reason but CSS, and then, use a class instead of IDs, problem solved.

Comment: I've editted my question

Comment: I really don't see a reason to specifically use IDs and not classes, even for test cases.

Comment: I am not the one who came up with it and I have no way to change the way it will work, I'm just wondering if the thing I've written about in my question may be a mistake later.

Answer (score 0):

You can see my fiddle that is based on your code.

[Setting same 'id' on different element](https://jsfiddle.net/Canet/Lfy3kyhs/1/)

```
$scope.changeType = function (){
    if($scope.type===1){
        $scope.type = 2;
    } else if($scope.type===2){
        $scope.type = 1;
    }
};
```

This is handled by using 'ng-click', so it might be able to far from perfect for your purpose.

And if you use 'ng-if', you can set same 'ID' on different elements.

But using same id is not good because anybody doesn't know when errors occur from that.

And welcome every feedback. :)

Answer (score 0):

**To answer your question, Yes.**

In the setup you outlined, it's ok since only one element is present in the DOM at a time.

I ran into the same situation, due to existing restrictions. After looking at the [`id` attribute](https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/elements.html#the-id-attribute) according to W3, as long as there is only one element with the ID in the DOM tree, it should be ok. `ng-if` removes the element from the DOM so it should be acceptable.

**NOTE: Some of the folks in the comments made some very good point. It is generally bad practice to have multiple elements with the same ID, as noted in the comments. Read comments for more info and to get the context.**